# Publish Snapshot vs Publish Release in Gradle With Continuous Integration

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, nexus

I'm just learning Gradle, coming from both an Ant+Ivy and Maven background and I'm trying to wrap my head around the proper way to publish a release version of my software using gradle.  I also need to constantly integrate my projects without having to constantly release independent artifacts.

**Ant + Ivy**

In the Ant + Ivy world, I can create publishSnapshot and publishRelease targets.  These can each use different Ivy resolvers to resolve and publish to my separate snapshot or release repositories in Nexus.

**Maven**

With Maven, I can define a `snapshotRepository` or `repository` in my `distributionManagement` section to have maven publish to my separate snapshot or release repositories in Nexus.

**Gradle**

Now enter gradle.  How can I achieve this same functionality?   I am using ivy style repositories.

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

**ANSWER**

Thanks to René's answer below, I was finally able to create a workable solution.  The crux of the matter was that I needed to constantly integrate across all my projects.  To do this I thought that declaring a dependency using version number `latest.integration` was the only way to pull in the latest version of my libraries, and therefore I needed to use ivy style repositories.

In fact, there are other ways to pull in the latest version of libraries in order to continuously integrate my software across all projects.  The solution is to use the `uploadArchives` exactly as René has listed below (also note you will need to `apply plugin: 'maven'` for this to work.  Make sure your repositories are also maven style, and when declaring a dependency, you can use dynamic version numbers as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370422/gradle-getting-the-latest-release-version-of-a-dependency). In my case, I listed a global version number in my common.gradle and in downstream projects, I used `version: version` to reference the global version variable.  In this way, each artifact in my system has the same version.  When it's time to release, I can change this from 1.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0 and build each one in order.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can configure the *snapshot* and the *release* repository in the 'Upload' task (e.g. the `uploadArchives`) task:

```groovy
uploadArchives {  
    repositories {  
        mavenDeployer {  
            repository(url: 'http://myCompanyRepo.com:8081/releases') {  
                authentication(userName: 'admin', password: 'password');  
            }  
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://myCompanyRepo.com:8081/snapshots') {
                authentication(userName: 'admin', password: 'password');  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

For `*-SNAPSHOT` versions the `snapshotRepository` is used. Otherwise the *releases* repo is used.

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified that I am using ivy style repositories.  i will update the question.

Comment: Nexus does not support ivy style repositories. It is m uch better to use a Maven repository format since it is understood by all build tools including Maven, Gradle, Gant, sbt, Leiningen, Ivy and others..

Comment: I seem to be able to publish with ivy settings to Nexus?  I need to publish as ivy in order to use latest.integration.  If I switch to a maven repo format in Nexus I won't be able to use this feature.

Comment: i overcame the latest.integration limitation by using dynamic revision numbers which allowed me to use maven repo format and implement your solution above.  updated the question with the answer

Comment: Quick point on publishing ivy settings to Nexus. It will resolve the library but not the transient libraries. Something to be aware of. The reason for this is because it expects to find a pom with the library, which lists the dependencies, and there is none- only the ivy.xml

Comment: Just re-emphasizing: gradle automatically selects snapshotRespository instead of repository depending on whether `project.version` ends in `-SNAPSHOT`. That's a bit to magic for my liking but for now I'm just glad I can do what I want.

Answer (score 58):

If you want to use the new `maven-publish` plugin, you can upload to different repositories using an `if` statement:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

...

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "anonymous"
            }
            
            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "http://example/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
            } else {
                url "http://example/artifactory/libs-release-local"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [maven-publish and setting snapshotRepository and releaseRepository](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-and-setting-snapshotrepository-and-releaserepository/5549)

Comment: So what is the advantage of this solution compared to just using the maven plugin?

Comment: Hi, if you use maven classifier and generate an archive, you need to use maven-publish, so this answer is very helpful. Thank you

Comment: reference link is dead. How do you conditionally set the `project.version` ?

Comment: @janosch maven plugin is now deprecated

Comment: The new reference link should be https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-and-setting-snapshotrepository-and-releaserepository/5549

Comment: thanks @Warlock, I've just updated the link