# Using a gradle plugin in a project where its dependency also use the same plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to gradle (leaving from maven). Now I have a problem. I have a gradle build where I want to use the `com.bmuschko.nexus` plugin. But my project depends on another project where I also want to use the `com.bmuschko.nexus` plugin.

So when I build I get an Exception:

```
Plugin 'com.bmuschko.nexus' is already on the script classpath. Plugins on the script classpath cannot be applied in the plugins {} block. Add  "apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.nexus'" to the body of the script to use the plugin.
```

But when I do so -> Add `apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.nexus'` to the body of the script to use the plugin I get another exception:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.bmuschko.nexus']
   > Plugin with id 'com.bmuschko.nexus' not found.
```

How can I solve this?

settings.gradle

```
include ':config'
project(':config').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../zConfig')
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
        // id "com.bmuschko.nexus" version "2.3" // already in classpath
        id "me.champeau.gradle.antlr4" version "0.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
//apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.nexus'

dependencies {
        compile project(':config')
}
```

EDIT: to reproduce just clone the repo https://github.com/KIC/stackoverflow/tree/master/gradleproblem and try `gradle tasks` in the bar directory

EDIT2: Seems that I could solve the nexus upload problem by omitting the plugin and follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16766946/1298461

But since I have also an antlr project and a second antlr project extending the grammar of the first, I have the very same problem just with another plugin. I think I could solve this when I use a parent build.gradle and subprojects{}. But this is exactly the reason why I leave maven and move to gradle. My sub-modules can and should also live independently with different versions.

Comment: It seems that if the plugin is already applied you can just use it. No need for reapplying it but just pass configuration and run appropriate task. Are tasks from mentioned plugin outlined when `gradle tasks` run?

Comment: Sadly no, since the project is in dependecies the setup will not work an thus gradle fails `Could not find method nexus() for arguments`

Comment: Is that project hosted online?

Comment: @Opal no its not online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'com.bmuschko.nexus' plugin is already on `config` project. That's the reason of the following error: *Plugin 'com.bmuschko.nexus' is already on the script classpath. Plugins on the script classpath cannot be applied in the plugins {} block. Add  "apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.nexus'" to the body of the script to use the plugin.*

I did the following:

Edit build.gradle (config project)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply from: '../repos.gradle'
```

Edit build.gradle (bar project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-nexus-plugin:2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.nexus'
apply from: '../repos.gradle'

dependencies {
        compile project(':config')
}
```

Then I run `gradle tasks` and everything is ok.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant contents of the repos.gradle file?