# Plugin error on importing gradle project into another

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am from Maven background and very new to Gradle. Given below is the context.

I have a library project

> LibraryStarter

which needs to be imported to a

> LibraryUser

project.

Both are spring boot projects and the build.gradle of **LibraryUser** complains that

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip'.
> Build file 'C:\WORK\LEARN\User\LibraryStarter\build.gradle' line: 2
> Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version:
> '2.3.4.RELEASE'] Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath
> must not include a version

I tried to apply the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741188/using-a-gradle-plugin-in-a-project-where-its-dependency-also-use-the-same-plugin?answertab=active#tab-top), but did not helped.

Keeping both the build.gradle files for reference.

For **LibraryStarter**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'  version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}



group = 'com.sample.library.starter'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation project(":MyLibrary")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

For **LibraryUser**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sample.library.user'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation project(":LibraryStarter")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

#################### UPDATE #################

Updated the build.gradle as requested by @Onur in comments. But the spring dependencies are removed from classpath and caused compilation errors in classes.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.sample.library.user'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":LibraryStarter")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

###################### UPDATE ########################

I got it working. But not sure if I am doing it right.

Removed the plugins from the **LibraryStarter** and added the following dependencies.

> implementation group: 'org.springframework',       name:
> 'spring-context',    version: "${spring_version}" implementation
> group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure',
> version: "${springboot_version}" implementation group:
> 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context'
> implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name:
> 'spring-cloud-commons'

If you think this is the right approach, I can post it as an answer. Else I am still open for your suggestions.

Keen to know the best and valid approach to handle this situation, rather than applying any patch!.

Comment: You're using the same dependencies in the two of the projects. Try to put the same dependencies in one common place. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070739/plugin-request-for-plugin-already-on-the-classpath-must-not-include-a-version

Answer (score 0):

if your module structure is like

```
root (LibraryUser)
 |__build.gradle
 |__sub-project (LibraryStarter)
    |__build.gradle
```

then in the root build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'  version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

Do not add (remove) plugins section in the sub-projects

Comment: LibraryStarter is not a sub project. Assume it as a dependency in Maven terms.