# Maven-publish gradle plugin skips the version

Tags: java, maven, gradle, kotlin

I have gradle multi-module project configured with kotlin-script. I'd like to add publishing to maven repository and I found `maven-publish` plugin for it. But it seems to skip the version configured for each project:

`MyProject/build.gradle.kts`:

```
subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("maven-publish")
    }
    configure<PublishingExtension>() {
        publications {
            repositories { ... }
            create<MavenPublication>("myPublication") {
                from(components.getByName("java"))
                logger.lifecycle("test: ${project.group} ${project.name} ${project.version}")
            }
        }
```

`MyProject/subproject1/build.gradle.kts`:

```
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

`gradle publish` output:

```
test: my.project subproject1 unspecified
artifact file does not exist: '.../MyProject/subproject1/build/libs/subproject1.jar'
```

File `subproject1.jar` doesn't exist, but `subproject1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` does. How to make gradle get the correct version of module?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem while using the `maven-publish` plugin:

I was trying to set the repository `URL` depending on project version as described in the [gradle docs here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:snapshot_and_release_repositories) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760035/3066295).

But I found the `version` always resolved to (as in the question) as the default (un-set) value: **`unspecified`**.

> *So I guess those documentation examples are for a project's `build.gradle` and not a general `gradle` script.*

Anyway, I believe the problem is due to the *timing of the execution* of the blocks in the `gradle` script. The `project.version` could not be accessed where I wanted it.  So I ended up passing a parameter to the `gradlew` command with the `-Pparameter` flag.

> Gradle has a `configuration` and then an `execution` stage.
>
> Refer to documentation:
>
> - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html
> - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch03.html
> - and an apparently similar problem, https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publication-closure-is-evaluated-too-early/19911

About your problem, it may be the same as I have described, or perhaps the reason is simpler:

- Looking at the structure of your `gradle` file, it does not appear to match the hierarchy specified in the [maven-publish documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).  In particular, `repositories {}` block should be at the same level as `publications {}`, not inside of it.

Possibly related:

- [Gradle maven publish plugin config has reference to dynamically created gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393179/gradle-maven-publish-plugin-config-has-reference-to-dynamically-created-gradle-t)
- [Gradle shouldRunAfter not available for a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253553/gradle-shouldrunafter-not-available-for-a-task)

Comment: posted solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067674/5079581