# Gradle shouldRunAfter not available for a task

Tags: gradle

I created [this repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/idea-scala-hate-each-other) to reproduce exactly what I'm seeing. I have a project that I'm building with Gradle. I would like to configure my Gradle build so that running:

```
./gradlew build
```

Has the exact same effect as running:

```
./gradlew clean build scalafmt shadowJar fizzbuzz
```

Meaning Gradle calls tasks in the following order:

1. `clean`
2. `build` (compile & run unit tests)
3. `scalafmt` (run a tool that formats my code to a styleguide)
4. `shadowJar` (creates a self-contained executable "fat" jar)
5. `fizzbuzz` (prints out "Fizzbuzz!" to the console)

According to the [Gradle docs on ordering tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks), it seems that I can use `shouldRunAfter` to specify ordering on all tasks...

If you clone my repo above and then run `./gradlew build` you'll get the following output:

```
./gradlew build
Fizzbuzz!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myUser/thelab/idea-scala-hate-each-other/build.gradle' line: 65

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'idea-scala-hate-each-other'.
> Could not find method shouldRunAfter() for arguments [task ':build'] on cz.alenkacz.gradle.scalafmt.PluginExtension_Decorated@6b24ddd7.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.983 secs
```

So even though I *specify* `fizzbuzz` to run last...its running first! And there are (obviously) errors with the rest of my config. And I'm not sure how to "hook" `clean` so that even when I run `./gradlew build` it first runs `clean`.

I'd be OK with a solution that requires me to write my own "wrapper task" to achieve the order I want, and then invoke it, say, via `./gradlew buildMyApp`, etc. Just not sure how to accomplish what I want.

---

### Update

I made some changes to `build.gradle` and am now seeing this:

```
./gradlew fullBuild
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:startScripts
:distTar
:distZip
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestScala UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
:clean
:fizzbuzz
Fizzbuzz!
:scalafmt
:shadowJar
:fullBuild
```

So when I run `./gradlew fullBuild` task execution seems to be:

1. `build` (which calls `compileJava` through `check`)
2. `clean`
3. `fizzbuzz`
4. `scalafmt`
5. `shadowJar`

So the ordering is still wrong even given my most recent changes...

Comment: You need to wrap the println in a doFirst/doLast block.

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth (+1) - any idea about the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oliver already stated, you need to put the console output to a `doFirst` or `doLast` closure, otherwise it will be executed when the task is defined (during *configuration phase*).

The exception is caused by the fact that both extension properties and tasks are added to the scope of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) object, but if both an extension property and a task with the same name (`scalafmt` in this case) exist, the extension property will be accessed. As the error message tells you, you are trying to access the `shouldRunAfter` method on an object of the type `PluginExtension`, where it does not exist. You need to make sure to access the task:

```
tasks['scalafmt'].shouldRunAfter build
```

---

#### Update

Actually, I thought that you only need the two specific problems to be solved, but already have a solution for your basic Gradle structure.

First of all, both `shouldRunAfter` and `mustRunAfter` do not actually cause a task to be executed, they only define the order **if** both tasks are executed (caused by command line or a task dependency). This is the reason why the tasks `clean`, `scalafmt`, `shadowJar` and even `fizzbuzz` are not executed if you call `gradle build`. So, to solve your first problem, you could let the `build` task, which you call explicitly, depend on them:

```
build.dependsOn 'clean', 'scalafmt', 'shadowJar', 'fizzbuzz'
```

But a task dependency will always run before the parent task, so all tasks will be executed before the `build` task. This should not be a problem, since the `build` task does nothing more than collecting task dependencies for all required build steps. You would also need to define the order not only between of your task dependencies, e.g. `clean` and the parent task `build`, but mainly between the existing task dependencies, e.g. `compileJava`. Otherwise `clean` could run after `compileJava`, which would delete the compiled files.

Another option would be to define a new task, which then depends on all the tasks you want to execute:

```
task fullBuild {
    dependsOn 'clean', 'build', 'scalafmt', 'shadowJar', 'fizzbuzz'
}
```

This would still require to define the order between your tasks and the existing task dependencies, e.g.

```
compileJava.mustRunAfter 'clean'
[...]
```

Please note, that now you would have to call `gradle fullBuild` from command line. If you really need to only call `gradle build` via command line and still execute some tasks **after** the actual `build` task, you could use a little trick in your `settings.gradle` file:

```
startParameter.with {
    if (taskNames == ['build']) {
        taskNames = ['clean', 'build', 'scalafmt', 'shadowJar', 'fizzbuzz']
    }
}
```

This piece of code checks the task name input you entered via command line and replaces it, if it only contains the `build` task. This way you would not have to struggle with the task order, since the command line tasks are executed consecutively.

However, this is not a clean solution. A good solution would include the definition of task dependencies for all tasks that **really** depend on each other and the invocation of multiple tasks via command line (which you want to avoid). Especially the hard connection between the `clean` and the `build` task bypasses a lot of useful features from the Gradle platform, e.g. incremental builds.

Regarding your second point in the update, it is wrong that the `fizzbuzz` task is running first. It is not running at all. The command line output is printed when the task is configured. Please move the `println` call to a `doFirst` / `doLast` closure:

```
task fizzbuzz {
    doFirst {
        println "Fizzbuzz!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lu.koerfer (+1) - please see my updates (I pushed them to my repo as well so you can reproduce). Still seeing a few issues regardging task ordering, any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your whole question. Also, you did not fix your `fizzbuzz` task yet.

Comment: Thanks @lu.koerfer (+1 again) - I like your `fullBuild` solution and would like to go with it. I made changes to the repo (please see the updated `build.gradle`) to include your `fullBuild` task, and also made sure that I put a [`doLast`](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/idea-scala-hate-each-other/blob/master/build.gradle#L61) closure to my `fizzbuzz` task. But **still**, when I run `./gradlew fullBuild`, the tasks run out of order (see my updated question with console output). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Now you need to specify the order: `tasks['compileJava'].mustRunAfter 'clean'` / `tasks['scalafmt'].mustRunAfter 'build'` / `tasks['shadowJar'].mustRunAfter 'scalafmt'` / `tasks['fizzbuzz'].mustRunAfter 'shadowJar'`

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible causes of that error could be because Gradle couldn't compile the `task` of the method `shouldRunAfter` or `mustRunAfter`.

Also it could happen when there is another entity of other type (not a task) with the same name of the `task` of the method `shouldRunAfter` or `mustRunAfter`. In this case you could use the syntax `tasks['task1_name'].shouldRunAfter tasks['task2_name']` or `tasks['task1_name'].mustRunAfter tasks['task2_name']` to make sure Gradle is referencing a `task` type entity.