# gradle suproject version is unspecified while publishing

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

i have two nexus repositories: one for releases, other for snapshots. i have code in publish task to define which repo to pick according to doc:

```
        repositories {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    credentials {
                        username "$nexusUser"
                        password "$nexusPassword"
                    }
                    def releasesRepoUrl = "https://xxx/repository/factoring-maven-release/"
                    def snapshotsRepoUrl = "https://xxx/repository/factoring-maven-snapshots/"
                    url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
                }
            }
            publications {
                create("default", MavenPublication.class) {
                    from(components["java"])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and subprojects included by this code :

```
rootProject.name = 'xxx-integration-lib'

include 'xxx-service1-dto'
include 'xxx-service2-dto'
```

subprojects build.gradle:

```
group = "xxx"
version = "0.0.6-SNAPSHOT"
```

but this doesnt work since subproject version is always unspecified.
tried:

1. making new allproject task to return version
2. using project.property('propName') - but this seems like a workaround, not a solution

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only worked way for me was a workaround:
placing subproject version management in root build.gradle like this

```
project(':subproject1') {
    version '0.0.6-SNAPSHOT'
}

project(':subproject2') {
    version '0.0.12-SNAPSHOT'
}

project(':subproject14) {
    version '0.0.5-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

and then project.version property is being injecting correctyl

Answer (score 0):

I am working on multimodule projects with gradle and we are not setting a version in submodules.All we do is setting it in base project in `gradle.properties` file.

```
group = "xxx"
version = "0.0.6-SNAPSHOT"
```

then you can use it:

```
url = project.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
```

Comment: well this doesnt answer the question

Comment: OK, you are right. One thing you can try is to add `-` before SNAPSHOT.
`url = project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
publishing {
    publications {
        nexus(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl = 'https://.../releases/'
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = 'https://.../snapshots/'
            url = project.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl

            credentials {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

use ***afterEvaluate*** block outside of publications and repositories block.

```
publishing {
    afterEvaluate {
        publications {
            nexus(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                def releasesRepoUrl = 'https://.../releases/'
                def snapshotsRepoUrl = 'https://.../snapshots/'
                url = project.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl

                credentials {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```