# In Gradle, how can I apply the subproject version to the `buildSrc` common publishing configuration?

Tags: gradle

After `gradle init`, I have several subprojects:

- app
- list (a library)
- utilities (a library)
- buildSrc (common config plugin)

I want to:

- configure publishing in `buildSrc`
- set `list` project version to `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
- set `utilities` project version to `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`
- then publish the libs to e.g. maven local

See the [example GitHub repository](https://github.com/terheyden/buildsrc-publishing). When I run `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`, the version is "unspecified" (a folder is created named:
`~/.m2/repository/com/example/utilities/unspecified`
instead of:
`~/.m2/repository/com/example/utilities/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`).

How can I get the subproject version to be applied to the publishing config? (The example project is Gradle Groovy, but if you could provide examples in both Groovy and Kotlin, that would be awesome.)

Comment: similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815923/gradle-suproject-version-is-unspecified-while-publishing   ;  it's not clear why this behavior. but a solution would be to move your `version` property in subproject from the `build.gradle` to  dedicated `gradle.properties` inside each subproject. I think the problem is due to version defined in subproject build.gradle not yet known when the publishing plugin is beeing configured.