# Gradle cannot find Maven parent dependency with version RELEASE

Tags: maven, gradle, build-dependencies

I've got a "project B" with a pom.xml like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

where "project B" has "project A" as parent project pom.

I am trying to create a new "project C" using gradle now and if I want to use "project B" as a dependency, I specify build.gradle like this :

```
repositories {
    maven {
         url "http://mycompany:8081/artifactory/repository"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.company', name: 'projectB', version: '0.0.1'
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Could not resolve org.company:projectB:0.0.1.
>
> > Could not parse POM http://company:8081/artifactory/repository/org/company/projectB/0.0.1/projectB-0.0.1.pom
> >
> > > Could not find org.company:projectA:RELEASE.

Appart from setting my projectA version number to an specific one, is there a way to make this build work with gradle?

Is there a way gradle could find the correct version like maven is doing right now? My other maven projects have no problem finding the correct version.

I do not want to get the latests version of project A, maybe downloading the full project B jar would be enough.

P.D I am using gradle version 4.5 and maven version 3.5.2 on my local computer

Comment: dont you have to put the RELEASE version that you are interested in? "RELEASE" is not enough....

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370422/gradle-getting-the-latest-release-version-of-a-dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - getting the latest release version of a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370422/gradle-getting-the-latest-release-version-of-a-dependency)

Comment: It seems like the same problem was exposed here:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-parent-poms-from-dependency-resolution-for-maven-artifact/5988 but I haven't found a suitable solution.

Comment: And this is also the same  issue, but no idea how to solve it: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-ignore-parent-pom-for-dependency-resolution/6155

Comment: You should simply put a literal version in there instead of using `RELEASE` something like `3.2.6`?

Comment: I am trying to find another way, because I do not own the real project b code. but I am starting to belive there is no other way

Comment: Could you verify if http://company:8081/artifactory/repository/org/company/projectA/ is listed in your artifactory?

Comment: Yes it exists but under it only the different versions folders are found, no pom. I mean there is only "company:8081/artifactory/repository/org/company/projectA/0.1" and  "company:8081/artifactory/repository/org/company/projectA/0.2" folders

Comment: Can you give us all your build.gradle files, even the project level one, not only the module level ones. If you didn't do it yet, put maven repository in the build.gradle file at level project either in the build section and in the dependencies section.

Comment: Only the called project C is in gradle. I will edit to write the full gradle file. Why would I need the local maven repo on the build section if I need this as a dependency? Anyway I tried it and didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

- Download the jar and pom of projectB from your artifactory.
- Change the pom by replacing "RELEASE" by a concrete version and the version tag of projectB by something new (like replacing version 1.2.3 by 1.2.3-manipulated).
- Upload the jar and the new pom to your artifactory.
- Reference version 1.2.3-manipulated from Gradle.

AFAIK you do not need to change the original jar or its content, it is enough to change and redeploy the pom file (with a different version that indicates your manipulation).