# Convert Maven dependency to Gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to convert below Maven dependency to Gradle:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
  <artifactId>foundationcore</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What would be the corresponding version in Gradle?

```
compile group: 'x.y.z', name: 'foundationcore', version:?
```

Comment: I got my answer. Plz refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370422/gradle-getting-the-latest-release-version-of-a-dependency/29492062 It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dependency</groupId>
    <artifactId>name-of-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

the gradle alternative would be:

```
compile group: 'org.dependency', name: 'name-of-dependency', version: 'RELEASE'
```

**EDIT**
It might be a shot in the dark because you simply didn't provide enough information but if you're still experiencing the problem even though compile group is correctly translated. It might be a problem with .m2 folder. But that's if you're talking about a local repository.

Comment: In my case, version is RELEASE not x.y.z. Same I need to convert to gradle

Comment: Shiba, if your dependency is public (and also not confidential) could you provide us with it? Note that if it is in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/), the Gradle script is provided so it is just a matter of copy-pasting inside your build.gradle.

Comment: yeah, my dependency is confidential not public. My maven build is fine and corresponding jar is available in maven central.

Comment: it always follows the same pattern I provided with my answer. In your case, x.y.z is just RELEASE.