# Can't get the latest version of a dependency on Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

Why Gradle can't get the latest version of a module when using this command : `implementation('com.example:module')`

But when I manually specify the latest version it works ! example :
`implementation('com.example:module:6.3.2')`

What could be the possible reasons for such a behaviour ? I know that without specifying the version it should get the latest version , but it's not the case for me now.

Comment: "I know that without specifying the version it should get the latest version , but it's not the case for me now." Because it's not true. You need to specify the version, [unless there is a BOM file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import) that contains the dependency and sets the version for you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370650/2000323

Comment: @LukasKörfer Thank you apparently I misunderstood the BOM file point !